# Form data is empty when calling HTTP.post() angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4

**this is my Post Call service.ts formData is coming as shown in alert but goes empty to API**

```
 addProduct (formData:FormData){
     let body=formData;
     alert(body.get('product_name'));
     return this.http
         .post(baseUrl+'api/Product/Create', body,httpOptionss)
         .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
 }
```

const httpOptionss = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
};

**This is what i get in API end** 
[image]

This is my product.ts code 
[image]

Comment: If you're using Reactive Form, you must send formData.value (not only formData)

Comment: Please don't use images to show your code, instead post it here. That will make debugging easier for other users :)

Comment: ok sir will be carefull with that image thing next time. And Yes i am using reactive forms.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'`
It work for me with `httpClient`